# Signal when new serial port is present

Tags: c++, linux, qt, events, serial-port

Is there a cross platform way to receive a signal (or other notification) in Qt, when a new serial port device becomes present, or one that was present before becomes absent? This is a simple case of getting to know when someone connected a new USB to serial port converter (discovering COM ports in windows and ttyS in linux). My only idea now is to periodically (for example using `QTimer`) run the `QSerialPortInfo` routines. Is there a way to accomplish this with event driven system? I would appreciate all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Qt 5.9, there is no such cross-platform way.

Whatever you'll do will be platform-specific.